# C++ program giving weird int value after looping

Tags: c++, c

So i tried below program with its expected output,

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int a[5];
    int len = *(&a + 1) - a; //length of array
    cout << "LEN:" << len << endl;

    //len = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }

    cout << "X  :" << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives expected output:

```
LEN:5
X  :0
```

Then i uncommented line 8 (`//len = 20;`) and tried again, which again gave the above correct output.

Then i commented line 8 and changed loop to `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {`, which gives below output,

```
LEN:5
X  :6
```

I was expecting `x` to be `0` since `x` has nothing to do with the loop (or does it?), then i got this `x` as `6`. Also it threw `Segmentation fault` which is also expected in line 10 (accessing out of bound). Could anyone please explain what cause for this behavior? It was compiled with `gcc` in windows environment.

(FYI: this is just an experimenting code)

Comment: `int len = *(&a + 1) - a; //length of array` Why would that be the length of the array, looks like UB to me?

Comment: @PiRocks i was testing pointers and things, saw it on a tutorial

Comment: You are accessing outside the bounds of an array so have undefined behaviour, anything could happen

Comment: @benjaminc Online tutorials are full of misconceptions and conjecture based on "it works on my machine so it must be correct".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, writing beyond the end of an array results in undefined behavior. This can cause unrelated code to change in unexpected ways.

The undefined behavior in your second example can be reduced to:

```
int main() {
  int a[5];
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    a[i] = i; // undefined behavior once i reaches 5.
}
```

If you're asking how this particular outcome is possible, if `x` and `a` are stored near each other on the stack, than modifying beyond the end of `a` could inadvertently change the value of `x`.

Determining what is going on with undefined behavior can become very difficult in larger programs, because the compiler is allowed a lot of freedom in deciding how and where to store variables. (and will potentially store them in multiple places simultaneously)